# ASP.CORE add custom folder to publication

Tags: asp.net-core

In my ASP.NETCore application in root I have some custome folder which a copie paste to publish folder after each publication

So my publication folder looks like this:

[image]

In MVC5  it was publishing automaticaly by configurations of application properties

[image]

**UPDATED**

I moved my folder inside wwwroot folder  so now VS includes it to publication , but now it's possible reach the files inside   by typing in browser url: https://domain/customefolder/secret.xml

So now I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to close access to some folder in wwwroot? If no
   then question two
2. How to include some  custom folder to be published ?

Comment: Does that folder have content inside? Did you try to set `Copy To Output Directory` setting to `Copy Always` on your files inside that folder?

Comment: Folder is not empty there is few files and folders inside and i need to pulicate this folder the same way wwwroot folder is

Answer (score 2):

There's no way I'm aware of to add a folder in general to be copied to output via the GUI in Visual Studio, only individual files. However, you can edit your .csproj file and add it there:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="MyFolder\" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Or, you may want to use `Content` with a glob:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="MyFolder\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I Update my post

Comment: Does updating your post change the correctness or not of this answer? The mechanism for "include things to be published" is, as Chris says, to use the `<Content>` tag in the `csproj` file. In the GUI, you can set it per-individual-file with `Properties -> Build Action`

Comment: Trying to get this to work now in a 2.2 project and the Publish action isn't picking up any of the content we've marked using `<Content Include="Folder\**">` and `<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</>`